# SequelizeJS returning "fulfillmentValue" with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I'd like to create an array of items using SequelizeJS and the `findAll` function but I get an issue.

The query has worked but I get a special object with somes unexpected properties (fulFillmentValue, isFulfilled, isRejected, ...).

[image]

**My code :**

```
associatedItems.includingItems = _.map(includeModels, function(includingModel) {
  return includingModel.model.findAll().then( function(items) {
    return {
      items: items,
      reference: includingModel.reference,
      modelName: includingModel.reference.replace(/_/g, '-')
    };
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below returns the Promise for the value, not the actual value you want.

```
function(includingModel) {
  return includingModel.model.findAll().then( function(items) {
    return {
      items: items,
      reference: includingModel.reference,
      modelName: includingModel.reference.replace(/_/g, '-')
    };
  })
}
```

Therefore, you have to get the value from Promise in the following way.

```
promises = _.map(includeModels, function(includingModel) {
  return includingModel.model.findAll().then( function(items) {
    return {
      items: items,
      reference: includingModel.reference,
      modelName: includingModel.reference.replace(/_/g, '-')
    };
  })
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    associatedItems.includingItems = results;
  });
```